# Pandas: how to use apply with a series of lists

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Pandas series of lists:

```
| id | values         |
| -- | -------------- |
| 0  | ['a', 'b']     |
| 1  | ['c']          |
| 2  | ['b', 'c']     |
```

I want to apply a function to each of the lists.

Let's use a really simple function that just adds 'd' to each list, and apply it to the series:

```
def append_d(x):
    print(x)
    return x + ['d']
my_series.apply(append_d)
```

This results in an error:

```
Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>
```

I have tried the following:

```
my_series.apply(lambda x: x + ['d']) # same error as above
my_series.transform(append_d) # ValueError: Transform function failed
my_series.transform(lambda x: x + ['d']) # ValueError: Transform function failed
```

How do I use apply/transform with a series of lists?

Comment: What is your pandas version? for me `df['values'].apply(lambda x: x + ['d'])` working nice in pandas `1.2.3`

Comment: Potentially you don't have a Series, but a DataFrame? Try `my_series['values'].apply(append_d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is need processing `Series`, it means column `values` instead `DataFrame` called `series`:

```
print (type(series))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print (type(series['values']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

---

```
series['values'].apply(lambda x: x + ['d'])
```

Better is called `DataFrame` `df` and then use:

```
df['values'].apply(lambda x: x + ['d'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `apply()` method:-

```
df['values'].apply(lambda x:x.append('d'))
```

Now if you print your `df` you will get your desired output:-

```
    values
0   [a, b, d]
1   [c, d]
2   [b, c, d]
```